# Почему font-family не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В классе **rotate** при изменении **font-family** шрифт не изменяется вообще, можно даже просто закоментировать его, всё равно остаётя тот же. Из-за чего это происходит и как починить?

```js
var rotates = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate');
for (var i = 0; i < rotates.length; i++) {
  old_height = rotates[i].offsetHeight;
  rotates[i].style.height = rotates[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
  rotates[i].style.width = old_height + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: default;
}

div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 0;
  width: 26px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 12px 3px 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6DAD53;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.rotate {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: -31px;
  background: #6DAD53;
  width: 22px;
  height: 90px;
  color: #eee;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* IE8 */
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <title>База данных головоломок v0.25 by Isaev</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="puzzles.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id='slideout'>
    <div class='rotate'>
      Настройки
    </div>
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все работает.. Чисто для теста поставьте **!important** для *font-family* , возможно его перекрывают другие стили. Ну и проверьте вообще работоспособность того шрифта что вы подключаете...

```js
var rotates = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate');
for (var i = 0; i < rotates.length; i++) {
  old_height = rotates[i].offsetHeight;
  rotates[i].style.height = rotates[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
  rotates[i].style.width = old_height + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: default;
}

div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 0;
  width: 26px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 12px 3px 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6DAD53;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.rotate {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive !important; // Поставьте !important для теста
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: -31px;
  background: #6DAD53;
  width: 22px;
  height: 90px;
  color: #eee;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* IE8 */
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <title>База данных головоломок v0.25 by Isaev</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="puzzles.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id='slideout'>
    <div class='rotate'>
      Настройки
    </div>
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Чёрт, как же так) А локально не работает... С !important тоже.
На что обратить внимание? В других стилях нигде не прописаны шрифты, всё по умолчанию. И вообще там писать правильно по-вертикали? Я ничего умнее не придумал, чем поменять на лету ширину с длиной

Comment: Ах, на шрифт линк нужен? Или на стандартные всё же не нужны? Например Arial и 'Times New Roman' должны отличаться в любом случае

Comment: @Isaev Откройте код в редакторе и поменяйте шрифты на лету, если у вас стандартные шрифты не работают, то скорее проблема со шрифтами непосредственно у вас на компьютере. Обратите внимание так же на то, что стандартные шрифты, они не для всех ос стандартные. Я сделал этот пример для того чтобы вы видели что все работает, значит проблемы в этом кусе кода нет.

Comment: да, разобрался уже, спасибо... Если подключать, все работают

Comment: на самом деле проблема оказалась тривиальной... Хром кешировал страничку и я не видел изменения, отключил кэш - стало легче жить) А то в последнее время, как в сказке было, меняешь элементарные вещи, а они не меняются!